# iOS - Is it better to use getter/setter methods directly or properties

Tags: ios, properties, getter-setter

I know that properties kind of encapsulate getter and setter methods. So whenever we say
myObject.property1 we actually cause to call [myObject property1]. From Apple documentation, Stanford iOS Courses and sample codes I can see that the usage of properties are encouraged. I aggree that using properties make a code look better and more understandable but what about performance? If I write a huge application will using properties have a noticableimpact on performance? Do professionals generally prefer direct setter and getter methods or properties?

Comment: My question is clear: Whether there's a performance difference between using dot notation (myObject.property1) and direct getter/setter calling ([myObject property1])? It's not something related to @synthesize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in performance when you use the bracket notation (`[myObject property1]`) or the `.` notation (`myObject.property1`).

This is more of a coding style than any thing else, so use the notation you are comfortable with or the same notation as your team if you don't work alone.

Comment: You say there's no performance difference between the two styles. I actaully love properties. And with later recent XCode version it's really easy to use them as XCode will share half the code writing. But it's a bit strange that it does not make any difference, I mean doesn't it take longer because it first has to translate those properties into getter/setter methods? Or does this translation take please in compile time? If it's so then voila.

Comment: They compile to the same thing, so there is no performance difference.

Answer (score 2):

Properties are probably better because they automatically generate the methods for you and when you synthesize them you can do it like this:

```
@synthesize property = _property
```

To avoid any confusion

Also you can choose different functions/methods like:

```
           (nonatomic, retain) // or (readonly) etc.
```

It also handles the memory better

Comment: but if you have MANY MANY properties from same class you want to make might as well make return methods...

Answer (score 1):

Properties are definitely preferred. It is the `@synthesize` statement, by the way, that generate the getters and setters automatically. There are no reports known to me that would corroborate performance changes with setters / getters.

Comment: Wrong. The key question is about performance. All other remarks are peripheral. I am addressing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Property syntax translates directly to getter/setter calls.  I have no idea which takes longer to *compile*, or if there is a difference, but when the program is running the code execution is the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you use declared properties, the getter and setter are generated at compilation time so there is no impact on the performance whatsoever compared to declaring your getter and setter yourself.

cf. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html